# Next.js revalidation on slug page don't work

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, sanity

i'm using Next.js and Sanity as CMS. I have an author page [slug].tsx and i'm trying to revalidate this page by using an api like revalidate.ts.
The author page index can revalidate informations like the number of posts by authors.
Only the author page slug can not revalidate. In this page, i have some informations of author like the number of posts and those posts.
I don't have any problems in local mode. Just in live mode.

In revalidate.ts, i replace the '${slug}' by the slug name of an author (for example: john-doe).
`await res.revalidate(`/authors/${slug}`);`
by
`await res.revalidate(`/authors/john-doe`);`
The revalidation work fine.
Using revalidatePath() not working.

Next i modify the authors/[slug].tsx to pass the slug in the body :

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<AuthorSlugProps, Query> = async (ctx) => {
  const { draftMode = false, params = {} } = ctx
  const client = getClient(draftMode ? { token: readToken } : undefined)

  const [settings, navigation, { authors }] = await Promise.all([
    getSettings(client),
    getNavigation(client),
    getAuthorBySlug(client, params.slug),
  ])

  if (!authors) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  const { slug } = params
  return {
    props: {
      authors,
      settings,
      navigation,
      draftMode,
      token: draftMode ? readToken : '',
      // Transmit params.slug to the body
      res: {
        json: {
          paramSlug: slug,
        },
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    },
  }
}
```

And in the revalidate.ts file :

```
...
const paramSlug = body.paramSlug
...
    switch (type) {
      case "post":
        await res.revalidate("/"); // OK Revalidate all pages
        await res.revalidate(`/posts/${slug}`); // OK Revalidate post page slug
      case "authors":
        await res.revalidate(`/authors`); // OK Revalidate all authors page
        if (paramSlug) {
          await res.revalidate(`/authors/${paramSlug}`);
        }
    }
```

But modifications don't work.